# PropTypes warning even when react-if's condition attribute is false

Tags: reactjs

We're using `react-if` in our render methods for any non-trivial logic and a ternary otherwise.

Turns out we get a warning saying that an object wasn't sent to `MyComponent` in the example below (due to its propTypes). This is because `person` is null and we expect `MyComponent` to not be rendered. Looks like `<If>` creates/initialises `MyComponent` even though the `condition` attribute is false.

```
import {If, Then} from 'react-if'
...

render() {
  const person = null

  <If condition={!!person}>
    <Then>
      <MyComponent person={person} />
    </Then>
  </If>
}
...

const MyComponent = ({person}) => (
  <h1>{person.name}</h1>
)    

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  person: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Any nicer way around this than setting person to `{}` or using a ternary if?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your person prop can be null, it should not be required.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  person: PropTypes.object
}
```

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/7291) for changing this ambiguous behavior this month and this will be reflected in the new release.

Comment: The person prop should never be able to be null as <If>'s condition attribute will be false and its contents never created (or so I thought). But turns out <If> goes into its children and send along the props, even when its condition is false. Good link to the merge request though, the new error message is a lot better.